# How can I improve performance of UI updates when two views are updating at once?

Tags: android, multithreading, performance, view, android-youtube-api

I am currently designing an application that has multiple views updating at the same time. One of the views is being faded from transparent to semi transparent.

The problem is that if the user interacts with the second view while that transition occurs then it becomes jerky and choppy.

**The animation of fading is done with the following code:**

```
ObjectAnimator colorFade = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(mBackView, "backgroundColor", new ArgbEvaluator(), 0x00000000, 0xbb000000);
colorFade.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
colorFade.setDuration(2000);
colorFade.start();
```

and  the update of the other view is done by recalling invalidate. I have already called invalidate on only the bit of screen that needs updating, I have already reduced my code in my onDraw() method so that it is absolutely minimal, and I have already reduced the number of times invalidate is called to an absolute minimum.

Is there anyway I can have both these views updating (one shading and the other invalidating) without this jitter?

And if anyone wants to know why I am using two view instead of just changing the color of the other view, this was was actually less jittery.

A 15 second clip can be seen here [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MvfqOKMATuc&feature=youtu.be) which demonstrates the problem. when I swipe over the controls and it invalidates the fade animation is jittery while when I keep still it is smooth.

Thank in advance!